# Samsung Health Duplicated Values

Tags: java, android, healthkit, samsung-health

I have an android app that read health data from Samsung Health and browse it. I added Samsung Health sdk version 1.4.0 and started to fetch the data using HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest to read different data values like total step counts, distance and active time. I could read the count of steps and distance from HealthConstants.StepCount. I read all the steps records and calcuated the sum of all these records values but the result was equal to the steps count when choosing Mobile phone + All steps.
My question is how can I choose the data which I want to fetch (Mobile phone or all steps).

```
private void readSteps(){ 
HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(mStore, null);

HealthDataResolver.Filter filter = null;
if(mReadDataRequest.getStartTime() != 0.0)
    filter = HealthDataResolver.Filter.greaterThanEquals(HealthConstants.StepCount.START_TIME, mReadDataRequest.getStartTime());

HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest.Builder()
        .setDataType(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE)
        .setTimeBefore(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
        .setFilter(filter)
        .build();

try {
    resolver.read(request).setResultListener(result -> {
        ArrayList<BaseHealthKit> stepCounts = null;
        try {
            for (HealthData data : result) {
                int count = data.getInt(HealthConstants.StepCount.COUNT);
                double distance = data.getDouble(HealthConstants.StepCount.DISTANCE);
                String startTime = data.getString(HealthConstants.StepCount.START_TIME);
                String endTime = data.getString(HealthConstants.StepCount.END_TIME);
                float burnedCalorie = data.getFloat(HealthConstants.StepCount.CALORIE);

                if (stepCounts == null)
                    stepCounts = new ArrayList<>();

                StepCount stepCount = new StepCount();
                if (startTime != null)
                    stepCount.setStartTime(Long.parseLong(startTime));
                if (endTime != null)
                    stepCount.setEndTime(Long.parseLong(endTime));
                stepCount.setCount(count);
                stepCount.setDistance(distance);
                stepCount.setmBurnedCalories(burnedCalorie);
                stepCounts.add(stepCount);
            }
        } finally {
            result.close();
        }

        if (mReadDataListener != null)
            mReadDataListener.onSucceedReading(stepCounts);
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Getting sleep data fails.", e);
} finally {
    disconnect();
}
```

}